# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'int'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am a C++ developer and recently moved to C#. Now I am dealing with a textbox in my WPF app where I need to set the test of the textbox. Here is the code:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="Data11" MaxLength="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Data11}" />
<TextBox Name="Data12" MaxLength="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Data12}" />
```

ViewModel Class:

```
private string _Data11;
    public string Data11
    {
        get
        {
            return _Data11;
        }

        set
        {
            _Data11 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data11");
        }
    }

// Description of Data12
private string _Data12;
public string Data12
{
    get
    {
        return _Data12;
    }

    set
    {
        _Data12 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Data12");
    }
}
```

Now on this textbox I need to set the text. Basically In my C++ app I had done it as follows:

```
m_matchData11->setText(String(String::toHexString((buffer+0), 1)), false);
m_matchData12->setText(String(String::toHexString((buffer+1+4), 1)), false);
```

If you notice above, **ToHexString** Creates a string containing a hex dump of a block of binary data. I tried doing this in My WPF app as follows:

```
Data11 = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 1);
Data12 = BitConverter.ToString((buffer + 4), 1);
```

Although first statement seems to work fine, second one throws the following error:

`Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'int'`

How can I achieve it? :)

Comment: So, you're trying to find the 4th element of the byte array?

Comment: show us the definition of `buffer`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Looks like the error is pointing that the buffer is a byte[].

Comment: And is the expression `(buffer + 4)` supposed to be address arithmetic?  If so, that's verboten in managed code like c#.

Comment: @digaomatias: yes, I got that.  Still should see the actual definition, both to be sure, and because it may better explain what is being attempted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the overload of the [BitConverter.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0965864.aspx) method which accepts a starting index and length.

```
Data12 = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 4, 1);
```

This will get the 5th byte in the buffer.

If you were not using `BitConverter.ToString` and had to do manual manipulation, you can use Linq's `Take` and `Skip` extension methods.

EDIT:

If you're only ever formatting 1 byte of the buffer, you may be able to do this instead:

```
Data12 = buffer[4].ToString("X2");
```

Comment: Thanks :) Here is the format of `toHexString(const void *data, int size, int groupSize = 1)`. Does `BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 4, 1);` perform the same operation? :)

Comment: You don't need a method of your own to display a hex string.

Comment: I just realized that you're only formatting 1 byte at a time, you might be able to forgo BitConverter and just do `Data12 = buffer[4].ToString("X2");`

Comment: @Matthew: `Data12 = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 4, 1);` and `Data12 = buffer[4].ToString("X2");` seem to give same result